# Why this question is not constructive?

Tags: discussion

This question asked for some books as evidence.

so this question was closed by the reason that it asks for list.

when I removed asking of lists instead of opening it I see it is closed still:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/is-research-about-checking-authenticity-of-the-hadithes-in-bukhari-collection-pe#comment10023_5325

> closed as not constructive by goldPseudo♦ 8 hours ago
>
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this
>   question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for
>   guidance.

why instead if opening another reason is said?

this makes me think they are only excuse for closing this question.

now I do not understand why this question is not constructive?

what is constructive exactly?

not constructive is a general reason and highly depends on who decides if it is constructive or not.

it is possible one due to his hack of knowledge about Islam decide that a question is not constructive. but another think it is constructive.

what is constructive and it should be constructive in view of who?

what if a question is constructive in a view and not constructive in another view?

Answer (score 0):

It is reopened, but it is still a discussion type question. 
 How to research about authenticity of that hadith after 1000 years?. Sunni muslims belive that it is correct and and shites belive that it is wrong. So it will result non constructive debates